# Can I use adapter to adjust Q-Factor like curved cranks?

Tags: crankset

So I just picked up an FSA power meter that is 386 EVO compatible and I replaced my FSA crank , but then realized that my original  FSA crank is curved and the power meter crank is straight so it hits rear chainstay.. Is there any adapter or spacer I can use to have it clear the chain or should i just get get curved cranks.

[image: FSA Straight crank]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture makes it appear you stuck a BB386EVO crank into a BB30/PF30 bottom bracket without [BB386 adapters](http://shop.fullspeedahead.com/en/type/bottom-brackets-spares/adapter-bb386-crank-for-pf30-bb30-frame):
[image]

Comment: Yes you are RIGHT!  I didnt use any adapters, so that's how you get around the curvature, just pop those adapters on the spindle, will that still allow the crank teeth enough catch onto the spindle grooves?

Comment: Presuming what you've got now is a normal BB30 or PF30 shell on the frame (measures 68mm across for a road bike), yes.

Comment: Do I need to put these adapters on both sides of the crank arm or just on the LEFT (non-drive side)?

Comment: Both. When you buy them it should be a set of two.